# using a namespace in c#

Tags: c#, console, namespaces, windows-phone

I am creating a game for windows phone in C# and I want to test out some output and other data through the console. How do I include the classes (or the namespace) from the phone application into a console project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the top of your source code:

```
using YourNameSpace;
```

Ensure that you have the code library referenced in your project, like so:

1. In your *Object Explorer*, locate **References**
2. Right-click **References** and select **Add Reference...**
3. Locate the DLL that contains your namespace either in the GAC or through the *Browse* tab

Comment: and probably it's worth mentioning that the project should have a reference to another project/assembly that contains those classes

Comment: Visual studio is not finding my namespace... Do I provide a path?

Comment: @zerkms Already made that edit. :) Thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus Right click on your Object Explorer where you have **References**.  Then click add Reference and locate your DLL code library that contains that namespace.

Comment: I see some DLL files, which one(s) do I add? Or do I add an entire folder?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus You have to add the DLL file(s) that contain your namespace(s) that you are referencing in your project.  Documentation on those code libraries would give you a better idea as to which references to add.

Answer (score 1):

with using  eg

```
using MyGameStuff;
```

or if you don't do that,  in your code...

```
var sprite = new MyGameStuff.Sprite ();
```

If you have put your classes in a different assembly ( project ) then you need to add a reference to your project / assembly.

If you don't have the project in your solution, then you may also need to add the project to the solution, then reference the project from your main app.